# Ruby Homebrew Support

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm, homebrew

My `brew doctor` command is getting this warning:

```
Ruby version 2.0.0 is unsupported.
Homebrew is developed and tested on Ruby 1.8.x, and may not work correctly
on other Rubies. Patches are accepted as long as they don't break on 1.8.x.
```

command result in:

```
$ brew --config
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.9.5
ORIGIN: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew
HEAD: c06d6be63fdefdeef6867d13035f84442b1b4888
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
CPU: quad-core 64-bit sandybridge
OS X: 10.8.5-x86_64
Xcode: 5.0
CLT: 5.0.0.0.1.1377666378
LLVM-GCC: N/A
Clang: 5.0 build 500
X11: N/A
System Ruby: 2.0.0-247
Perl: /usr/bin/perl
Python: /usr/bin/python
Ruby: /usr/local/bin/ruby
```

I don't have older version of Ruby < 1.8.x

Answer (score 1):

Ruby 1.8 is very outdated, so don't use it. See [Ruby 1.8.7 retired](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/06/30/we-retire-1-8-7/). I'm not sure if there are any issues with 2.0.0 but you can always use 1.9.3 through RVM.

Also, I'm not even sure if there is a dependency to use brew with Ruby - I can't see a reason why, but I may be wrong.

You can install a more recent version of Ruby through RVM assuming you have it installed.

Check what's there:

```
rvm list
```

To install:

```
rvm install 1.9.3
```

Switch to 1.9.3

```
rvm use 1.9.3
```

Comment: `rvm use 1.9.3` will only temporarily switch to that version if RVM is defaulting to another version, which it would be if it's already installed and the OP had been using it. The full and correct command is `rvm use 1.9.3 --default` which will tell RVM to use 1.9.3 as its default when a shell starts.

Comment: Homebrew formulas are written in Ruby so yeah, it depends on Ruby for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Homebrew is written and tested to use the standard system ruby, which is 1.8 (at least on my Mountain Lion install)

That warning is telling you that it may not work correctly under your installed version (2.0.0)

If everything is working fine then you can probably safely ignore the warning.

Answer (score 0):

The ruby comes with Maverick is 2.0 and I was able to install homebrew using ruby 2.0.